# Unable to determine reason for output of c code

Tags: c

I have the following code. I cannot determine the reason for the output it's giving.

```
char abc[14] = "C Programming";

printf("%s\n", abc+abc[3]-abc[4]);
```

output:rogramming

It is a quiz question with the following options: What would this print? a)C Programming b) rogamming c)Runtime Error d)Compilation Error

Comment: And why does this violate your expectations?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Because abc[3] and abc[4 ]alone  should give error so I am confused if its concatenated or something else is going on.

Comment: @reaper1 You need to include like that in your question. Your question borders on unanswerable in its current form because it's not even clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Pointer arithmetics: get difference of  ASCII values of abc[3] and abc[4], and add the result to abc

Comment: @Carcigenicate It is a quiz question with the following options \n What would this print?
  a)C Programming
 b) rogamming
  c)Runtime Error
  d)Compilation Error

Comment: This depends on the underlying character set, which makes it a bad quiz question.

Comment: @teppic the result would be the same with the EBCDIC character set, since `'o'` to `'r'` are also consecutive.

Comment: @WeatherVane - it's not a requirement though, a quiz question on C shouldn't depend on things outside of C.

Comment: @teppic I take your point, some character set may have resulted in "c) Runtime Error."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it will be clearer if I put in stepping stones `v3` and `v4`. These are used to calculate an offset into the string of 3 indices. So the print output begins at `abc[3]`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char abc[14] = "C Programming";
    int v3 = abc[3];
    int v4 = abc[4];
    printf("%d - %d = %d\n", v3, v4, v3 - v4);
    printf("%s\n", abc + v3 - v4);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
114 - 111 = 3
rogramming
```

Answer (score 2):

This may caused by the following:
the value of `abc[3]` is 'r',the value of `abc[4]` is 'o'.so the value of

```
abc[3]-abc[4]
```

is 'r'-'o',change the value into `int` is `3`.So when you use `printf("%s\n", abc+abc[3]-abc[4]);`,it means you print this string from abc[3].
the following code will show you something.

```
 int main()
  {
  char abc[14] = "C Programming";
  printf("%d\n",abc[3]-abc[4]);
  printf("%s\n", abc+abc[3]-abc[4]);

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In this expression `abc+abc[3]-abc[4]` there is used so-called the pointer arithmetic.

An array name in expressions is converted to pointer to the first element of the array,

Thus in the expression above abc points to the first character of the string that is to  `'C'` `abc + 1` points to space. `abc + 2` points to 'P'. `abc + 3` points to 'r' and so on.

expressions abc[3] and abc[4] are converted to type int and equal to internal codes of characters `'r'`  and `'o'` The difference of these codes is equal to 3,

Thus expression `abc+abc[3]-abc[4]` can be written like `abc + 3` and points to the forth element of the array that is to `'r'` So the string starting from 'r' is outputed by statement

```
printf("%s\n", abc+abc[3]-abc[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

On virtually every platform (e.g. one using ASCII), the behaviour is undefined. So, none of the answers is correct.

```
abc+abc[3]-abc[4]
```

This expression is equal to

```
abc + 'r' - 'o'
```

the values of character constants are implementation-dependent; assuming an ASCII system, where `r` and `o` are 0x6f and 0x72, respectively, `abc + 0x6f` is out of the bounds of the array `abc`, leading to undefined behaviour. Note, that the later subtraction, appearing to bring the result back into bounds, doesn't change that; once reached, one cannot recover from undefined behaviour.

That said, the result is likely to be the same as `abc + ('r' - 'o')`, which, on an ASCII system, is `abc + (0x6f - 0x72)`, which in turn is `abc + 3` and thus `rogramming` is outputted, as reported in the question.